# How to push from Github to Sharepoint Online page using pipeline?

Tags: github, sharepoint, continuous-integration, documentation, pipeline

I'm interested in making a set of detailed documentation with a group of people, but need to track changes in the way github works. Like every line, and by who and when. But I want the final changes to appear on a sharepoint online page each time I publish on github. How can I set up a clean and efficient way to push from github to sharepoint online pages?

Comment: Not exactly what you asked, but look at “Versioning in SharePoint”https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/community/versioning-basics-best-practices

Comment: See also https://automate.io/integration/github/microsoft-sharepoint